# Nothing shows up when replace is set as true in my Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS. I wrote a simple directive. It only works when replace is set as false. The funny thing is that it is supposed to be true if I understand correctly. You can find the code at https://jsfiddle.net/F52y5/86/.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="bugTrackerApp" ng-controller="bugTrackerController"><bug-tracker title='abcde' bugs='bugs'></bug-tracker></div>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('bugTrackerApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('bugTrackerController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.bugs = [
        { severity: 'high', id: '10000', summary: 'summary 1' },
        { severity: 'med', id: '20000', summary: 'summary 2' },
        { severity: 'low', id: '30000', summary: 'summary 3' },
        { severity: 'low', id: '40000', summary: 'summary 4' },
        { severity: 'low', id: '50000', summary: 'summary 5' },
        { severity: 'low', id: '50000', summary: 'summary 6' },
        { severity: 'low', id: '50000', summary: 'summary 7' },
        { severity: 'low', id: '50000', summary: 'summary 8' },
    ];
}])
.directive('bugTracker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            bugs: '='
        },
        template: "<accordion><accordion-group is-open='true'>" +
             " <accordion-heading>{{formatTitle()}}</accordion-heading>" +
             "  <table class='bug-review'><tbody ng-repeat='bug in bugs'><tr ng-class=getTrClass(bug.severity)><td>{{bug.id}}</td><td>{{bug.summary}}</td></tr></table>" +
             "</accordion-group></accordion>",
        controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            $scope.formatTitle = function () {
                return $scope.title + ' (count=' + $scope.bugs.length + ')';
            }
        }],
        replace: false,      
        transclude: false    
    };});
```

Please note that the replace flag is currently set as true so the content shows up.

Comment: You have error in console which is clearly explains the problem. I also recommend to use newer versions of libraries. Also jsfiddle is not very convenient for angular demos, consider plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: I did not see any error in console. How can I see it? The issue is that it works fine when replace is false but not set as true. I never used plunker before, i just copied my html and script but it does not run. Can you kindly take a look at it? Thanks. http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2

Comment: Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/DgMfzXjiEZuaYXlhg2w0?p=preview

Comment: And here is the explanation why it doesn't work with replace true: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=bugTracker&p1=accordion&p2=template&p3=%3Caccordion%20title%3D%22abcde%22%20bugs%3D%22bugs%22%3E

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand why it does work with replace true.

Comment: What version of angular are you using? I think around 1.4 they removed that functionality.